# ¿Como Validar que el valor proporcionado sea un numero entero y no un string/caracter?

Tags: c++, validación, dev-c++

Estoy tratando de realizar una validación para que el programa solamente permita ingresar números del 1 al 3, sin embargo al ingresar algun char o string se cicla he intentado con la librería:

**#include <ctype.h>**

Para utilizar **isdigit()** pero al realizar la prueba de la validación el programa se cicla mostrando el texto de *"Favor de proporcionar una Opción Valida."* Una y otra vez sin permitir ingresar otro dato.

¿Existe alguna manera de detenerlo o existe otra forma de validar el tipo de dato?

...

```
int iOpcionFigura = 0;
// Introduccion para que el usuario seleccione una opcion
cout << "Calcular Areas de Diferentes Figuras! \n" << endl;
cout << "¿Que figura desea Calcular? \n" << endl;
cout << " 1 - Rectangulo" << endl;
cout << " 2 - Circulo" << endl;
cout << " 3 - Esfera \n" << endl;

//Se guarda el valor de la opcion seleccianada
cout << "La opcion seleccionada es: ";
cin >> iOpcionFigura;
cout << "\n";

//Validamos que la opcion proporcionada sea realmente un numero valido
while( iOpcionFigura < 1 || iOpcionFigura > 3 || isdigit(iOpcionFigura)){
    // Se repite la instruccion hasta que proporcione algun valor valido
    cout << "Favor de proporcionar una Opcion Valida.\n" << endl;
    cout << "La opcion seleccionada es: ";
    cin >> iOpcionFigura;
    cout << "\n";

};

cout << "Continuo sin problemas" << endl;
```

...

Muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> isdigit(iOpcionFigura)
> ```

Está mal. `iOpcionFigura` es un número. `isdigit` es aplicable a los caracteres. La problema es, un caracter es *también* un número, por lo tanto el compilador no se queja. Sin embargo, esta expresión no tiene sentido en este contexto.

`isdigit('2')` es verdadero, `isdigit(2)` no. `'2'` y `2` son cosas muy diferentes.

Si el usuario ingresó un número, no tiene sentido validar `iOpcionFigura`, es un número. Si el usuario *no* ingresó un número, `cin >> iOpcionFigura` *ha fallado*, `iOpcionFigura` no ha cambiado, no tiene nada que validar. Es posible verificar **`std::cin`**, pero `iOpcionFigura` no.

Hay varios maneras de validación, quieres aprendelos.

1. Entrada de entera línea.

   ```
    std::string linea;
    // leer una linea
    if (std::getline(std::cin, linea)) {
       // usar una función comp stoi o strtol
       // para convertir la línea
       // estas funciones indican si la entrada no es un número
       // stoi lanza una excepción 
       // strtol indica el final de la entrada válida dentro de la cadena
    } else {
       // hay un error de entrada, quizás el fin de archivo o un error físico
    }
   ```
2. Entrada de un número

   ```
     if (!std::cin >> numero) {
       // hay un error de entrada
         if (std::cin.bad()) {
            // hay error físico, no se puede seguir
            // imprimir un mensaje y salir
         }  else if (std::cin.eof()) {
            // fin de archivo, no se puede seguir
            // imprimir un mensaje y salir
         } else if (std::cin.fail()) {
            // el parte interesante, el usuario ingresó un no número
            // descartar entrada inválida y el resto de la línea
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

         }
      } else {
        // el usuario ingresó un número válido
      }
   ```